# Бот бесконечно отправляет сообщение. Как решить проблему?

Tags: python, discord, datetime

````
@tasks.loop(seconds = 1.0)
async def welcome_seend():
  now = datetime.now().hour
  if now in [00, 6, 12, 18, 14]:
      channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813)
      await channel.send('```diff\n-Уважаемые сотрудники копропрации  контрольные  захват начнеться чрез два часа, будьте осторожнее при перемещении по зоне\n```')
  time.sleep(2)
````

Вот код, бот должен проверять время и скинуть сообщение, но он не прекращает отправку.

У меня есть идея почему, так как условие все время выполняется, но как переписать код так, чтоб он скидывал одно сообщение в определённые часы.

Answer (score 0):

````
@tasks.loop(hours = 6.0)
async def welcome_seend():
  now = datetime.now().hour
  if now in [00, 6, 12, 18, 14]:
      channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813)
      await channel.send('```diff\n-Уважаемые сотрудники копропрации  контрольные  захват начнеться чрез два часа, будьте осторожнее при перемещении по зоне\n```')
  time.sleep(2)
````

Решение было гениальным....
Всего-то заменить интервал между вызовом loop

Comment: А он теперь вообще срабатывает? Вполне возможно что тайминги будут кривыми

Comment: @oleksandrigo Верно ответили, теперь по таймингам проблемы, как можно решить?

Comment: Поставь раз в час